# HTTP redirect to URI with leading slash+blackslash "/\example.com" considered absolute on Chrome / IE

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, http, redirect

An HTTP request is sent to website `http://www.foobar.com/`,
the servers responds with the following HTTP `Location` header
(leading slash and backslah, followed by a hostname)

```
Location:/\example.com
```

Two behaviors can be observed depending on the browser being used :

- On *Google Chrome 43* (windows and linux), *Internet Explorer 11*, the browser then request the following URI (as if the location header value was a protocol relative URI):

  `http://example.com`
- On *Firefox 38*, *Safari 8*, *Epiphany* or *Curl*, the following request is performed :

  `http://www.foobar.com/\example.com`

As far as I understand the specification, the behavior applied by Chrome and IE is incorrect.

The **[HTTP 1.1 specification (RFC 7231)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.2)** defines `Location` header in section 7.1.2 [emphasis added] :

> The "Location" header field is used in some responses to refer to a
> specific resource in relation to the response.  The type of
> relationship is defined by the combination of request method and
> status code semantics.
>
> ```
> Location = URI-reference
> ```
>
> The field value consists of a single URI-reference.  **When it has the
> form of a relative reference ([RFC3986], Section 4.2), the final
> value is computed by resolving it against the effective request URI
> ([RFC3986], Section 5).**

The **[URI specification (RFC 3986)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2)** defines relative reference in section 4.2 [emphasis added] :

> A relative reference that begins with two slash characters is termed
> a network-path reference; such references are rarely used.  **A
> relative reference that begins with a single slash character is
> termed an absolute-path reference**.  A relative reference that does
> not begin with a slash character is termed a relative-path reference.

The only reference to this `/\` leading sequence that I could find is in the following post :
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/preventing-open-redirection-attacks

1. Do you have any explanation on why Chrome and IE interprets those URI as absolute ?
   Does it serve any purpose ?
2. Apart from protocol relative URI (`//example.com`), do you know any other "relative" URI which are in fact interpreted as absolute by some browsers ? (being a correct interpretation or not)

**Updated**

- Official bug report entered for Chrome :

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=500610

Comment: What is the purpose of the backslash in the request? Surely you don't mean the requested file (or directory) has a backslash in its name? If so, somebody ought to get fired.

Comment: Anyway, the way I see it, yes, it IS an absolute path, but absolute means at the root of the current domain, not the root of the internet, so `http://www.foobar.com/\example.com` should be chosen. Now I know IE always replaces backslashes with slashes (because it thinks that this helps Windows users who are typing backslashes by mistake), but I'm surprised that Chrome does it too. In IE's defence, there should be no backslashes in the name, so technically it shouldn't matter what it does with them!

Comment: @MrLister "What is the purpose of the backslash in the request?" it's precisely my question, I don't see any purpose in having URI starting with "/\". However the handling of IE and chrome may enlarge the attack surface on website which accepts relative redirect URL as parameter and did not think of such validation, and that's why I was wondering if anynone new a real use case or the reason behind IE/Chrome behaviors.

Comment: This sequence is clearly being checked in the ASP.net blog post, so I suppose it is a known behavior, at least for some people...

Comment: I see. Well, then the question becomes, "how can you prevent IE from treating backslashes as slashes?" I don't know if you can. Or, "how can I detect it when someone uses `\/` in an URL on my website?" But you said this was something your server did, not an outside attacker?

Comment: @all I am not looking for a solution to prevent this potential attack. Indeed, this is very simple to do in many ways : always convert URI to absolute URL, perform additionnal validation of this prefix, disallow redirect, etc. As stated in my original question, I am looking for an explanation of this IE/Chrome behavior (is there a reason   for it?) and for any other weird prefix that might trigger the same interpretation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an official Chromium Bug :

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=476478